# Bootstrap Typeahead.js Ajax call - way to add extra parameters?

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using bootstrap typeahead and I have the following code:

**Script.js**

```
$('#demo7').typeahead({
            ajax: {
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: '@Url.Action("List", "Partials")',
                data: { something: 35 },
                triggerLength: 1 
            },
            scrollBar: true,
            displayField: 'Name'
        });
```

**PartialsController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult List(string query, string something)
        {
            try
            {
                return Json(this.GetList());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw;
            }
        }
```

And I want to know how can I pass extra parameters to the controller, I try to put data: { something: 35 } in AJAX call but in the controller this parameter is always null... any idea to pass extra parameters?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Option*, you can use *Source*, and then do an ajax call normally.
Have a look at this https://gist.github.com/thorst/2960885